# Blackberry How to access Contacts from Contact List of Phone

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am developing one application in that i have contact details ,when i click the contact number it will ask some option like call.How to access contact list in blackberry so that  it should show contact list of phone.
Just similar to the image shown:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BlackBerryContactList list = (BlackBerryContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
PIMItem contact = list.choose();
```

This lets you navigate, edit, and choose a contact. After that you can use the chosen contact's information to call, or sms, etc.

If the native selector isn't what you want, iterate over the entries in list and build your own.